# Problems with iterating over my Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have an object as follows:

```
{ monday: { close: '10:30 PM', open: '07:30 AM' },
  tuesday: { close: '07:00 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  wednesday: { close: '05:30 AM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  thursday: { close: '11:00 PM', open: '06:00 AM' },
  friday: { close: '01:00 AM', open: '01:30 AM' },
  saturday: { close: '07:30 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  sunday: { close: 'Closed', open: 'Closed' } }
```

I'm trying to iterate over this and populate an array.

//get the hours of operation

```
 Space.getSpaceById(req.body.spaceId, function (error, space) {

    if (error)
        throw error;

    var hours = space.hoursOfOperation;

Object.keys(hours).forEach(function(key) {
            console.log(hours[key]);
            hoursArray.push({open: hours[key].open, closed: hours[key].close})
        });
}
```

my getSpaceById method..

```
 module.exports.getSpaceById = function (id, callback) {
        Space.findOne({_id: id}, callback);
    };
```

I keep getting an error when calling .open and .close

my hours object is declares as this in mongoDB

```
hoursOfOperation: {
        monday: {open: String, close: String},
        tuesday: {open: String, close: String},
        wednesday: {open: String, close: String},
        thursday: {open: String, close: String},
        friday: {open: String, close: String},
        saturday: {open: String, close: String},
        sunday: {open: String, close: String}
    }
```

Comment: console is logging what?

Comment: When I try the code I don't get any error. What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: `forEach` has more arguments available? And how exactly are you "calling" open and close ?

Comment: This is my error: hoursArray.push({open: hours[key].open, closed: hours[key].close})
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: and what does `console.log(hours[key]);` give  ?

Comment: Sure seems to work -> https://jsfiddle.net/3gmw5eLa/1/

Comment: the console.log gives  close: 'Closed', open: 'Closed' }
{ close: '07:30 PM', open: '11:00 AM' }
{ close: '01:00 AM', open: '01:30 AM' }
{ close: '11:00 PM', open: '06:00 AM' }
{ close: '05:30 AM', open: '11:00 AM' }
{ close: '07:00 PM', open: '11:00 AM' }
{ close: '10:30 PM', open: '07:30 AM' }

Comment: thats so strange that it is not working

Comment: show the full `hours` object declaration code

Comment: edited my question

Comment: it doesn't look like full definition, but anyway, you have trouble on misusing the object's name

Comment: no, I am getting the hoursOfOperation from the database and saving it into a variable called hours. When I console.log(hours) it prints the object fine

Answer (score 0):

I pasted the code in a JSBin, and made a couple of changes, this works fine, without changing very much of your code:

```
  var hours = { monday: { close: '10:30 PM', open: '07:30 AM' },
  tuesday: { close: '07:00 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  wednesday: { close: '05:30 AM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  thursday: { close: '11:00 PM', open: '06:00 AM' },
  friday: { close: '01:00 AM', open: '01:30 AM' },
  saturday: { close: '07:30 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  sunday: { close: 'Closed', open: 'Closed' } };

var hoursArray = [];
Object.keys(hours).forEach(function(key) {
            console.log(hours[key]);
            hoursArray.push({open: hours[key].open, closed: hours[key].close});
        });
console.log('----HoursArray here:----');
console.log(hoursArray);
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/viciduk/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error- typeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Comment: when i declare hours as you are doing above, it works. But when i set the hoursOfOperation from my database to hours, it does not work. Even tho im retrieving the hoursOfOperation just fine

Comment: { monday: { close: '10:30 PM', open: '07:30 AM' },
  tuesday: { close: '07:00 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  wednesday: { close: '05:30 AM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  thursday: { close: '11:00 PM', open: '06:00 AM' },
  friday: { close: '01:00 AM', open: '01:30 AM' },
  saturday: { close: '07:30 PM', open: '11:00 AM' },
  sunday: { close: 'Closed', open: 'Closed' } }

Comment: that is the object i get back after querying my db

Comment: I get the space by id and it is return. I'll add the getSaceById method

Comment: where are you GETTING it, the function looks fine, where do you require it and use it to actually get the data? Somewhere you must do that, where that happens, is the issue, if your're not using that function anywhere thats why.

Comment: I fixed it.  var hours = space.toObject().hoursOfOperation;

Answer (score 0):

Just use the for-in construct.

```
for (var key in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hours = foo[key];
        console.log(hours.close + " " + hours.open);
    }
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somrlik/mpqrtxgh/2/)